# no module named modeller

Tags: matplotlib, python-2.7

i have started using python for using modeller software for modelling proteins. i have a plot script for plotting graphs it has a module named pylab and its not working with the modeller CMD prompt with windows7 software. and while running the same script by using python shell it showing importerror no module nemed modeller. when i asked to my higher officials he asked me to set PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables. but i dont know how to do it..can u explain me how to set the path in layman format which i can understand easily. but then too i have tried Advanced setting->environmental variables and setting variables but i do not know how to set the path for each variables..please some one guide me with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is some documentation [in the python docs](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#configuring-python) for how to deal with this, but it sounds like the confusion is on what to set the variable to.

If you start your command prompt (cmd.exe in the start menu), you can set a variable by using the command

`SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib`

The `PYTHONPATH` variable describes the location of the modules so python knows where to look to find them. It looks like a list of filepaths separated by semicolons.

What this command does is set the variable `PYTHONPATH` to its current value (the `%PYTHONPATH` part), adds a semicolon, and puts `C:\My_python_lib` at the end of the list.

You need to find the path to the pylab module (probably a folder named "pylab" with a file called `__init__.py` in it) and add it's location to your `PYTHONPATH`